# ¿Cómo cambiar límite de memoria en macos?

Tags: php, macos

Estoy teniendo este error porque el límite de memoria no me permite esta capacidad. Tengo un macos 14.2.1 pero no sé como puedo acceder al php.ini y modificarlo y como aplicar los comandos una vez dentro.

- Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 106971136 bytes) in /Users/robertorp/Desktop/Proyecto_Istrad requerimientos y practicas/views/alumnos/index.php on line 184

Agradecería si alguien me pudiera decir que pasos tengo que seguir.

Comment: en un terminal `php --ini` , si es web te conviene modificar el setting por proyecto via `.htaccess` o `.conf` o `.fpm.ini`

Comment: Y luego que pasos tengo que realizar?

Comment: es para cli o web?

Comment: Lo necesito para uso local mi ordenador

Comment: en tu uso local de ordenador accedes al script por terminal (cli) o via navegador (web) ? btw, proba setear desde el script mismo `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); `

Comment: accedor por el terminal por eso no se si lo de poner ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); me va a funcionar

Comment: `ini_set(` permite modificar valores del `php.ini` por script, sea web o cli. si el `ini_set(` está deshabilitado lo pones en el `.ini` correspondiente por ej `/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini` buscas y reemplazas o agregas la confi `memory_limit=512M`. Para cli / terminal suele estar desactivado el limite : `# grep -nir 'memory' /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini` -> `430 : memory_limit = -1`

Comment: Antes de pensar en aumentar el límite de memoria, te recomendaría que revises tu script. ¿Por qué excede un límite de memoria nada despreciable, cuando el límite por defecto en PHP es de 128Mb? ¿Acaso no hay algo mal escrito en tu código? Otra cosa es que estés trabajando en algo muy pesado, como transmisión de imágenes en tiempo real enviadas desde la luna o cosas por el estilo.

Comment: deberias poder poner un php.ini en el directorio raiz de tu proyecto y hay le metes las directivas que te hagan falta y deberian sobre escribir las que tiene php por defecto ... ese tipo de cambio se le llama variable local...

Comment: tambien si dentro de tu index.php colocas: `phpinfo();` te debera decir como esta configurado tu entorno.